# Ansible XML - Retrieving Just the Value of the Match

Tags: xml, ansible, jinja2

I have an XML file that I am trying to get the value from 'id'. The problem is I have only been able to retrieve this:
"{http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2015/06/nuspec.xsd}id": "data_wanted}".

I am just looking to return only 'data_wanted' and not the long associated key name.

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2015/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>data_wanted</id>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I have the following ansible play to register into 'nuspec_value'

```
- name: Get nuspec value
  xml:
    path: files/office.nuspec
    content: text
    xpath: /x:package/x:metadata/x:id
    namespaces:
      x: http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2015/06/nuspec.xsd
  register: nuspec_value
```

And here is the debug output for 'nuspec_value.matches'

```
- name: Output nuspec
  debug:
    var: nuspec_value.matches

TASK [Output nuspec] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
"nuspec_value.matches": [
    {
        "{http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2015/06/nuspec.xsd}id": "data_wanted"
    }
]
```

I will only ever get 1 match in the XML document for 'id.' 'id' is being returned as a list, and so I can reference nuspec_value.matches[0], but it always brings along the

```
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2015/06/nuspec.xsd}id
```

I just want the value of 'id,' which is just 'data_wanted.'

How do I go about doing a set_fact: and just extracting the value of the matches and storing only the result of id which is 'data_wanted'? I was hoping I could just do nuspec_value.matches[0].value. When I tried 'nuspec_value.matches[0].value,' I get this error

```
- name: Output nuspec_value.matches[0].value
  debug:
    msg: "{{ nuspec_value.matches[0].value }}"

TASK [Output new_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'value'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/examples/chocolatey/initialize_chocolatey.yml': line 46, column 13, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n          - name: Output new_fact\n            ^ here\n"}
```

I was hoping for a solution proposed somewhat like this:
e.g.

```
pseudo-code:
set_fact: new_fact = (nuspec_value.matches filtered somehow)

debug:
  var: new_fact

TASK [Output new_fact]
*******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "new_fact": "data_wanted"
}
```

Update:
My most recent attempt, this gives the value, but I am not a fan of how readable it is. I could store the namespace in a variable, but Id like to know if there is a better way to refrence/filter the result

```
debug:
  msg: "{{ nuspec_value.matches[0]['{http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2015/06/nuspec.xsd}id'] }}"

TASK [Output new_fact] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "data_wanted"
}
```